# Checking an integer array for duplicate values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, integer

Following is my code:

```
$array1=('23','3','55','67');
function has_dupes($array1){
 $dupe_array = array();
 foreach($array1 as $val){
  if(++$dupe_array[$val] > 1){
   return true;
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```

I'm new to PHP and wanted to write a function to check an array for duplicate integers. My code is below:

It gives an error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' on line 1`

Comment: Using something like array_count_values() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) or array_unique() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) might be an easier approach.... e.g return (max(array_count_values($myArray)) > 1);

Comment: Echo echo echo echo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_unique`](http://www.php.net/array_unique) to perform this check easily. Just compare length of original array against the length of the unique version of the array.

```
function has_dupes($array){
  return count($array) != count(array_unique($array));
}
```

Also you want to declare an array using [`array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php).

Answer (score 3):

you missed `array` keyword

```
$array1 = array('23','3','55','67');
         ^ // here was the mistake
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function has_duplicates($myArray) {
    return (max(array_count_values($myArray)) > 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is that you are using the wrong array syntax. Correct would either be

```
$array1 = ['23','3','55','67']; // only possible in PHP >= 5.4
```

or

```
$array1 = array('23','3','55','67'); // all versions of PHP
```

Regarding the dupe detection function, you don't need one because there is a ready-made one you can use: `array_unique`.

```
if (count(array_unique($array)) != count($array)) {
    // the array has dupes
}
```

Comment: @j0k: Well, it's been out for almost a year now. I added a comment to clarify anyway.

Comment: I know, sadly PHP 5.4 isn't really used in comparison to PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1= array(23,3,55,67);
```

Thread integers as integers.

Answer (score 1):

By putting the numbers in quotes, you're treating them as string. Also, the array syntax is wrong...

```
$array1 = array(1,2,25,26);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the error

```
$array1=array('23','3','55','67');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this?

```
$array1 = array_unique($array1)
```

Have I misinterpreted the question?